# Function returns only one column when return type is record type postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I have a function that has the return type of record.

Below is the function am using, basically what the function does is , it takes in input paramter and queries the database to return the columns:

```
drop function if exists test_proc(sr_number1 bigint);
create or replace function test_proc(sr_number1 bigint) RETURNS record /*SETOF tbl*/ AS $$

declare
i integer default 0;
record_type record;
begin
select sr_num,product_number,phone,addr into record_type from my_table where sr_num=sr_number1;
return record_type;
end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Unfortunately, when I execute the function as

select test_proc(12345);  I get the result as a comma separated list in just one column like (sr_num,product_number,phone,addr). But what I was hoping to have it return was a table row with the column values and their respective column names.

I also tried executing the function as

```
select * from test_proc(12345); but get the following error

ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
```

Comment: `select * from` is the correct way to use a function that returns a result set. You can declare the function as `returns table (...)` then you don't need to specify the column names when you select from the table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name how should the return type be ? could you please post the modified function of my version of code? I tried to return the table but could not get it worked out.

Answer (score 2):

When querying a function that returns a record you must specify the type of record you want to get in the result

```
 select * from test_proc(12345) f(b bigint, t text);
```

This should work.

A better solution is to declare the type of record in the function

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_proc(sr_number1 bigint) 
 RETURNS TABLE(b bigint, t text) AS $$  $$
```